# If statement only prints first line

Tags: c

I have a problem my if statement only seems to be able to do the first line of the code

sentence is HELLO
it should print HOBELLOOB, but all it does is repaces all vowels with O

```
for (int i = 0; i <= sizeof(sentence); i++)
{
       if (sentence[i]=='A' || sentence[i]=='E' || sentence[i]=='I' || sentence[i]=='O' || sentence[i]=='U' || sentence[i]=='Y')
       {
            temp[i] = ob[0];
            temp[i+1] = ob[1];
            temp[i+2] = sentence[i];    
        }
        else
        {
            temp[i]=sentence[i];
        }
}


printf("\n%s",temp);
```

Comment: What is the logic for adding OB?

Comment: After you've written `"HOBE"` to `temp`, what's the next thing that will be written to `temp`, and which element(s) of `temp` will be affected?

Comment: Please provide a [mre], ideally with hardcoded sample input, output and desired output.

Answer (score 1):

You need two counter for the indexes. Otherwise the contents in temp will be overwritten on the next loop.

```
int j=0;
for (int i = 0; i <= sizeof(sentence); i++)
{
   if (sentence[i]=='A' || sentence[i]=='E' || sentence[i]=='I' || sentence[i]=='O' || sentence[i]=='U' || sentence[i]=='Y')
   {
        temp[j++] = ob[0];
        temp[j++] = ob[1];
        temp[j++] = sentence[i];    
    }
    else
    {
        temp[j++]=sentence[i];
    }
}


printf("\n%s",temp);
```

Comment: so simpel but that actually did the trick

Comment: Would be nice if you accept the answer